# On modal close, swiper slider image index is not changed

Tags: php, ajax, swiper.js

Slider retaining the value of slide index, it is not setting to zero for other images in slider.

Once I opened the modal and close the modal, the slider index is remain same for other modal open.

Comment: Please edit your post with your code so we can more easily and faster, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try put method mySwiper.update(), or mySwiper.update(true) for hard update, when close modal